# What are the usual logic voltage levels in MCUs and other modules?

Tags: microcontroller, logic-level, vcc

It's a 100% beginner's question.

Assuming that I have a device with VCC = 5 V, is it true that HIGH level will be always something around
this 5 V and LOW level will always be something around 0 V?

Or there are some exceptions to the rule?

Comment: also, a HIGH is not necessarily a logic `1`

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple standards. It is also not a single level but a range. Input ranges and output ranges are also different. The output range should always be contained by the input range, never the other way around.

- **Vih** - input high - any voltage higher than this is read as high
- **Vil** - input low - any voltage lower than this is read as low
- **Voh** - output high - a high output is always at least this voltage
- **Vol** - output low - a low output is always at most this voltage

And not near the power rails since the range is then too small, especially for inputs.

[image]

https://www.eetimes.com/a-brief-recap-of-popular-logic-standards/#

[image]
https://www.edn.com/secrets-of-level-translation-revealed/

Comment: When in doubt, **read the datasheet** -- particularly if you're interfacing between logic families, and always if you're working with a component that's not _in_ a logic family (like a microprocessor or a sensor or whatever).  You'd really rather get an unpleasant surprise at the datasheet-reading stage than the staring-at-a-non-functioning-board stage.

Answer (score 1):

Older MCUs (ones with 5 V or 3.3 V supply) generally have a single supply pin (called VDD), and internal logic and IO use the same level -- i.e. a logic 0 is 0 V, and a logic 1 is VDD level. Sometimes there is a separate pin for the IO level (so that for instance, VDD could be 3.3 V, while IO is at 5 V).

Newer MCUs use 1.8 or lower voltages internally, and this is not usually useful for IO, so IO *does* have a separate supply and a generally higher value. For interface to DRAM or other peripherals (e.g. PCI bus), there may be a special IO voltage regulator and level.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can answer such questions yourself by looking them up:

- Open up the datasheet for the MCU. Some MCUs keep the datasheet and reference manual separate, others keep them in the same document. Generally the datasheet is for the hardware design and the reference manual is for the software design. In this case we are interested in voltage ratings, so that would be the datasheet.
- No matter datasheet, there will be a chapter *Electrical characteristics*. Below it, you will find several sub chapters, the relevant ones in this case are addressed below:
- *Absolute maximum ratings*. These are stress ratings that the part can handle for a short time. It's good to know in some cases, but not something you should design normal use of the part based upon.
- *Supply characteristics* or perhaps "general characteristics" will mention what supply voltages the part can handle. For example operating voltage (V<sub>DD</sub>) for a 3.3V to 5V tolerant part might be listed as min 2.7V and max 5.5V.
- There will also be another sub chapter called "DC characteristics" or "GPIO characteristics" or "I/O characteristics" etc. It will list input/output high voltages and low voltages, most often as an equation based on V<sub>DD</sub>.

  For example input low-level voltage 0.3V x V<sub>DD</sub> and input high-level voltage 0.7V x V<sub>DD</sub> means that if you supply the MCU with V<sub>DD</sub>=5.0V then:

  - Every GPIO input below 1.5V gets treated as low (binary zero).
  - Every GPIO input above 3.5V gets treated as high (binary one).
  - There's a span between 1.5V - 3.5V where your input voltages shouldn't be or the pin won't behave as expected. Inputs may read either as low or high and you can't rely on such reads to be correct or deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct. Most devices have a max value for what is considered a low value (0.6v for example), and a minimum value for what makes a high value (X volts for example on a 5v device). Any given brand or series may have different values.

In general, 4000 series logic chips can operate from 3 to 18volts
Many 7400 series and many older microcontrollers, CPUs and memory operate at 5v.
Newer stuff at 3.3v.
Low power and high speed stuff at 1.8v and even 0.9v.